# Count the number of checkboxes which are checked

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I want to count the number of checkboxes which are checked on my asp.net page and if the count = 5 then to change the button state from disabled to enabled.

I don't understand because when I clear the check in one checkbox ( from 5 checkboxes checked to 4 checkboxes checked ) the button state is enabled and not change state in disabled.

My code below.

I would greatly appreciate any help you can give me in working this problem.

```
protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chkTest = (CheckBox)sender;
    GridViewRow grdRow = (GridViewRow)chkTest.NamingContainer;

    int count = 0;
    if (chkTest.Checked)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkSelect");
            count++;

            if (chk.Checked && count == 5)
            {
                btnUpdate.Enabled = true;
                btnUpdate.CssClass = "enabledImageButton";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1**
Page_Load code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        GridViewBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the ASPX and Page_Load code?\

Comment: yes in EDIT 1 in my first post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the count after the loop and it should work as expected:

```
protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chkTest = (CheckBox)sender;
    GridViewRow grdRow = (GridViewRow)chkTest.NamingContainer;

    int count = 0;

    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
       CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkSelect");

       if (chk.Checked)
       {
         count++;
       }
    }

    if(count==5)
    {
        btnUpdate.Enabled = true;
        btnUpdate.CssClass = "enabledImageButton";
    }
    else
    {
        btnUpdate.Enabled = false;
        btnUpdate.CssClass = "disabledImageButton";
    }
}
```

Comment: @Hamamelis Kindly mark it as the answer to give credit to the responder.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have code to disable the button. Try the following code

```
protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chkTest = (CheckBox)sender;
    GridViewRow grdRow = (GridViewRow)chkTest.NamingContainer;

    int count = 0;
    btnUpdate.Enabled = false;
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
       CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkSelect");

       if (chk.Checked)
       {
          count++;
          if(count >=5)
          {
             btnUpdate.Enabled = true;
             btnUpdate.CssClass = "enabledImageButton";
             break;
          }
       }
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you for help, I tried your code but when I clear the check in one checkbox ( from 5 checkboxes checked to 4 checkboxes checked ) the button state is enabled and not change state in disabled.

Answer (score 0):

If you un-check then it will not go in this

```
 if (chkTest.Checked)
 {
```

when you remove check then you need to do calculation also.

Answer (score 0):

You are counting the number of checkboxes with you count, not the number of *checked* checkboxes
As such you code is always going to 'fire' if the 5th checkbox is checked, irrespective of the checkstates of the previous 4.

Looks like you want:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
    CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkSelect");
    if (chk.Checked) count++;
    if (count >= 5) 
    {
        btnUpdate.Enabled = true;
        btnUpdate.CssClass = "enabledImageButton";
        break; //Avoid hitting more rows than necessary
    }
}
```

this means that you will only *Enable* if at least 5 are checked,  as other posters have said you have nothing to disable it so it will stay enabled.